# Getting Job Accommodations when I have a Sleep disorder

Tags: salary, fulltime, scheduling, accommodation

I am in a bit of a quandary and would really appreciate any support from anyone here who is working on salary and preferably who also has sleep disorders. I am working from home at present from Oregon. My employer may have me work in a physical building located in Washington.

My employer has recently offered to give me a full-time salary, as I currently work on an hour-by-hour basis and have to clock in periodically, so it is part-time. It would be nice to be earning more money, especially since it'll help me get out of debt sooner and increase my savings. However, I have recently been seeing my primary doctor who referred me to a sleep doctor for an evaluation of a circadian rhythm disturbance, which is linked to the fact that I am completely blind and have no light perception. So, like my friends suspect, my doctors confirmed that I most likely have a [free-running sleep schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-running_sleep) or *non-24-hour sleep-wake disorder.* Even though I have done everything I could behaviourally to adjust my sleep cycle to a 24-hour cycle, I can never stay asleep for longer than four hours, even with help from taking melatonin. I was very fortunate to get and keep this job thanks to the Vocational Rehabilitation Programme, which is a federally-funded service that helps people with disabilities get support to retain employment.

Anyhow, since my question has to do with ways to accommodate this, I'm wondering if anyone here can recommend some ways for me to work something out for my employer. For instance, if I were to work on salary, would it be realistically possible for me to work two to four hours if I wake up in the middle of the night and can't get back to sleep, and hopefully that makes me feel tired again, so that I can get a few more hours of sleep, and then I can finish the rest of the four hours in the afternoon to complete eight hours. I know that [salaried employees](https://www.bamboohr.com/hr-glossary/salaried-employee) are not expected to work 40 hours a week or clock their hours, but that is something I am considering.

Comment: Can you say where you are as there may be laws relating to disability and accommodations specific to your locale?

Comment: I am from Oregon. I'll update it now.

Comment: Why can't you do 8 hours straight with breaks?

Comment: I haven't had any breaks to start out with (this is my first job), as I have been on SSI for eight years.

Comment: Why not discuss with your doctor? They will also have an idea of the regulations.

Comment: My primary doctor wrote a letter asking for a lighter workload or arranging early release, but my sleep doctor insists that I should be able to retrain my sleep cycle, which I'm already trying to do.

Comment: Can you tell us the type of job? Certain jobs may not be able to be time shifted.

Comment: My job is done on-line, most of it at my own pace, but sometimes I get booked for Zoom meetings as I teach music-related stuff there.

Answer (score 6):

> My employer may have me work in a physical building located in Washington.

It would be difficult to sleep during work at a normal workplace unless you can get your day split up. But working from home depending on what the job is you can make your own hours.

A lot depends on the sort of work. If you're doing a shift where you need to liaise with others or be on call then obviously it's a problem. But if you can find the sort of work where you're just expected to do a certain amount over a week then it's fine. Just discipline yourself to get everything accomplished. You're an adult so you must already know what strategies work for you in terms of time management.

In your particular situation I think your best option is to talk to your work (they already know you're blind) and try and negotiate a full work from home job. Going to a physical location creates multiple issues and will soak up some of your revenue.

Comment: I'll add this to my post, but my job is both on-call-based and work that you can do any time of day, as I am a music instructor but also do SEO stuff.

Comment: On top of what was suggested in the answer, since you are on-call, get a clear expectation on what should be your availability for fielding calls and response time - then you really have to try your best to meet that

Comment: One thing that I found helpful was that I had a two-hour shift, and then I was on call five hours later. I dozed and set a timer on my phone to keep myself from falling asleep. Then the drowsiness went away by the time I was expecting my student. I'd hate to let everyone down, and that thought alone is what keeps me from falling asleep.
As far as the other thing, my employer says that I can do those tasks and divide my hours as I see fit (I do a few different things a week), provided that I don't work more than a certain amount for budgetary reasons.